# Webparts in asp .net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to understand how webparts work exactly and what do they do.

I added a webpartmanager and a catalogzone to the page. My only problem is that I get a network exception like this:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I am guessing that the configuration for webparts is stored in a database but I can't find a connection string anywhere in the webpartmanager and I am pretty clueless how to set up the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open SQL Server Manager and enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP:

[SQL SERVER – FIX : ERROR](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)